# Obj loaded in Three.js not receiving light

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an Obj loaded in the scene. With MeshBasicMaterial, everything works fine. However, when I change it into MeshLambertMaterial, it's absolutely dark. Note that I have already set an ambient and a point light up and a Box just near the Obj model (everything is right in the camera) with MeshPhongMaterial shows up as expected. Also, to avoid setting normals the wrong way, I also assigned the "side" property of the material to DoubleSide as follows:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 'yellow', side: THREE.DoubleSide});
```

What's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried formatting the color in hexadecimal, as per the documentation?

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshLambertMaterial

A pure, bright yellow would be 0xFFFF00

Comment: @SamuelGoodell Without luck still...

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the trick is that I have to invoke computeFaceNormals() and computeVertexNormals() manually.